# Using variables in OkHttpClient

Tags: java, android

I have been trying to send a POST request with some user data. The request seems incomplete. I need help with this line

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
MediaType mediaType = MediaType.parse("application/json");
StringEntity postingString = new StringEntity(gson.toJson(pj));
RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(mediaType, "{\n   \"url\":\"https://okirizuri.herokuapp.com/check\",\"phone\":"  + phone + "\"}");
Request request = new Request.Builder()
        .url("https://okirizuri.herokuapp.com/lipa")
        .post(body)
        .addHeader("content-type", "application/json")
        .addHeader("cache-control", "no-cache")
        .build();
 String phone = editText.getText().toString().trim();

RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(mediaType, "{\n   \"url\":\"https://okirizuri.herokuapp.com/check\",\"phone\":"  + phone + "\"}");
```

The phone is a variable which has a user number but its not showing at the endpoint

Comment: you probably should define variable `String phone` _before_ accessing it ...and not afterwards. variable `RequestBody body` also is being defined twice, which is illegal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like in your example, you are missing an additional double quote right after \"phone\": which makes it invalid json. You've escaped a quote on the right hand side of the phone number but not the left side.

```
RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(mediaType, "{\n   \"url\":\"https://okirizuri.herokuapp.com/check\",\"phone\":"  + phone + "\"}");
```

JSON:

```
{
    "url": "https://okirizuri.herokuapp.com/check",
    "phone": 555-555-5555"
}
```

Should be:

```
RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(mediaType, "{\n   \"url\":\"https://okirizuri.herokuapp.com/check\",\"phone\":\""  + phone + "\"}");
```

JSON:

```
{
    "url": "https://okirizuri.herokuapp.com/check",
    "phone": "555-555-5555"
}
```